# API to convert document of different formats to Pdf

Tags: pdf

I need a API to convert any type of document to Pdf (free or purchase). Kindly suggest me efficient API provided by any vendor.
Thanking You

Comment: What do you mean by any type. Can you provide a list of formats, like .doc, docx, xls, xlsx etc.

Comment: For office documents (doc, xls etc) you can use openoffice.org's api. http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=63632 can help you start.

Comment: http://www.convertapi.com/ is effective.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what your platform is, so try [this platform agnostic one](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services/summary.aspx) I worked on. Examples: [Java](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/04/convert-office-files-to-pdf-format-from.html), [C#](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html), [VB.net](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2011/01/invoking-pdf-converter-web-service-from.html). The API is web services based and supports a large number of file formats with perfect fidelity.